# binding range of IPs in Centos, not working

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bind, ifconfig

I'm trying to bind 8 x /24 subnets in Centos. I set up the usual primary in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-eth0 for the default /29 assigned to the box. All good, I'm in ssh fine.

Now, I'm trying to add the additional 8 C classes of IPs using this method

```
cp -p ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0-range0
cp -p ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0-range1
cp -p ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0-range2

etc...
```

all the way through range7

I restart the network, first C class (range0) works fine, but range1-7 give off similar errors all the way through like this

```
error in ifcfg-eth0-range7: already seen device eth0:182 in ifcfg-eth0-range6
```

In network-scripts I have them as

```
fcfg-eth0-range0
ifcfg-eth0-range1
ifcfg-eth0-range2
ifcfg-eth0-range3
ifcfg-eth0-range4
ifcfg-eth0-range5
ifcfg-eth0-range6
ifcfg-eth0-range7
```

I even tried

Each range file loos like this...

```
[root@login-third network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0-range0
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR_START=xxx.xxx.38.2
IPADDR_END=xxx.xxx.254
```

range1 example...

```
[root@login-third network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0-range1
DEVICE=eth0:1
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR_START=xxx.xxx.39.2
IPADDR_END=xxx.xxx.39.254
```

I originally tried without the DEVICE line too, same errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a `DEVICE` in the range files.
But there should be a `CLONENUM_START`.
Setting that will correctly map the addresses to the virtual NICs without assigning the same device twice.

Example: in ifcfg-eth0-range0 you set `CLONENUM_START=0`.
xxx.xxx.38.2 => eth0:0
xxx.xxx.38.3 => eth0:1
...

In ifcfg-eth0-range0 you set `CLONENUM_START=255`.
xxx.xxx.39.2 => eth0:255
xxx.xxx.39.3 => eth0:256
...

See also:
https://wiki.centos.org/VladislavRastrusny/OneNICManyIPs

Comment: Ok, so eth0 is CLONENUM_START=0, range0 is CLONENUM_START=255, what would range1, range2, etc be? @faker

Comment: eth0 doesn't have a `CLONENUM_START`, only the range files do. This is really just the start where the naming of those interfaces starts. So if you assign eth0:0 through eth0:254 in range0 then you should start with 255 in range1 and so on.